# Why my app is starting in /private/var/folders/hl instead of it's real location

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, security

I get an application that I need to start in it's own folder instead of that it starts here:

`/private/var/folders/hl/dhpt8nq95tv84ptt9pl23hb40000gn/T/AppTranslocation/636B3A57-76A9-446C-B2AD-28B4A5571A34/d/`

how can I force it to start on it's original location ?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262570/oddly-randomized-mounted-paths-in-sierra-for-certain-apps/267441#267441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way I just moved my application and its dependencies from it's location to `~/Applications/` and its. I hope it will help someone.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to address the OP’s question.